# Problems binding parameters in a run "@path \ script.sql"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to automate the execution of a long query that has multiple steps. The result should be 16807, but when I run the following steps the result is 25. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm applying the "undefine" clause and applying the "define" clause again. Please help.

**Query 1 (filename paso_1.sql)**

create table aa_1 as

select &numero + 2 as calculo from dual

**Query 2 (filename paso_2.sql**

create table aa_2 as

select power(calculo,&exponencial) as resultado from aa_1

**Master Query**

undefine numero exponencial

define directorio='C:\Users\jvidarte\Desktop\prueba_sql'

define numero=5

define exponencial=5

@'&directorio\paso_1.sql';

@'&directorio\paso_2.sql';

select * from aa_2;

Comment: Possibly the tables already exist from a prior question/test, and the create tables are failing. Or the files in the directories don't match the files you have here. Looking at the contents of the aa_1 table should give a clue.

Comment: Thank you @GaryMyers. Solved with your help.